# Access denied to mysql database when lauched from Django's dbshell

Tags: mysql, django

I have just installed mysql in my mac system, and I have configured my Django `settings.py` for the mysql data base

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '/usr/local/mysql-8.0.23-macos10.15-x86_64/data/takeawaywebshop', #changed in production
        'USER': data['mysql']['username'],
        'PASSWORD': data['mysql']['password'],
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

When I launched the below command calling dbshell from manage.py, I received an error stating that the data base access what denied

```
python manage.py dbshell
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'jianwu'@'localhost' to database '/usr/local/mysql-8.0.23-macos10.15-x86_64/data/takeawaywebshop'
CommandError: "mysql --user=jianwu --password=xxxxxx /usr/local/mysql-8.0.23-macos10.15-x86_64/data/takeawaywebshop" returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Any ideas of what I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by changing the 'NAME' in `settings.py` to `takeawaywebshop` without providing the full path.